# Bitmap Rotate And Save Image

Tags: android

I would like to rotate and save the rotated image and move it elsewhere within my android device.

1. I am able to rotate my image and set it to image view.
2. I can copy an UN-ROTATED image to a destination of my choice.

The only thing I am unable to do is get the saved rotated image FILE (rotated.jpg)

My code below to rotate: (this does not save rotated file to storage?)

```
              Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePathLocal); 

              Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
              matrix.postRotate(getImageOrientation(filePathLocal));
              rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), matrix, true);          

              //Set Image
              ImageButton ibProfile = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibProfile);
              ibProfile.setImageBitmap(rotatedBitmap);
```

Now the above only rotates temporarily until the activity is ended, now I would like to save this rotated image from above code and move it somehwere before uploading it to server, I already know how to copy/move files and upload so no need to post those codes - all I need is the code for SAVING ROTATED IMAGE, so that I have something like /sdcard/saved_rotated_image.jpg

Comment: do you know how to save bitmap in file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePathLocal); 

          Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
          matrix.postRotate(getImageOrientation(filePathLocal));
          rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), matrix, false);          

          //Set Image
          ImageButton ibProfile = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibProfile);
          ibProfile.setImageBitmap(rotatedBitmap);
```

> Put false in the createbitmap's last argument

Refere my code:

```
@Override
    protected Uri doInBackground(String... params) {
        String filepath = params[0];
        String filename = params[1];
        String filetype = params[2];

        Bitmap bitmap = takeScreenShot(root);
        Matrix rotateMatrix = new Matrix();
        rotateMatrix.postRotate(Datas.rotationvalue);
        Log.e("rotationvalue", Datas.rotationvalue+"...");
        Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), rotateMatrix, false);

        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        rotatedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bytes);
        try {
            File f = new File(filepath); 
            if (!f.exists()) {
                f.mkdir();
            }
            String folderpath = f.toString();
            File file = new File(folderpath, filename + "." + filetype);

            file.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            fo.close();
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            Log.e("Edited img uri", uri.toString());
            return uri;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Exception...occured", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

This code is working fine.At my own side, try at your side.

> According to doc: last argument is filter boolean: true if the source
>   should be filtered. Only applies if the matrix contains more than just
>   translation.

Link for more info: [Last argument more info](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html)

Comment: Thanks, I just had to change Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG to Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG

Comment: Okay sure..but if this ans help you to get more info ,then kindly upvote it

Comment: I approved and upvoted, must have been a network interference, I'll do it again

Comment: @user3560827 Thank you bro,Received

Answer (score 1):

Save the image function is as follows:

```js
 private void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, String fileName) {
  File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), fileName);
  FileOutputStream fileOS = null;
  try {
   fileOS = new FileOutputStream(file);
   // quality: Hint to the compressor, 0-100. 0 meaning compress for small size, 100 meaning compress for max quality.
   bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fileOS);
   fileOS.flush();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  } finally {
   if (fileOS != null) {
    try {
     fileOS.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

Use the sample:

```js
   Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePathLocal); 

   Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
   matrix.postRotate(getImageOrientation(filePathLocal));
   rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), matrix, true);          

   saveBitmap(rotatedBitmap, "saved_rotated_image.jpg");
```